# Vim 3rd party color schemes come out weird

Tags: vim

I'm messing around with my color schemes in vim, and I can't get 3rd party ones to work right.

Here is what [mango](https://github.com/goatslacker/mango.vim) comes out like for me

[image]

pretty different than advertised.

some with [distinguished](https://github.com/Lokaltog/vim-distinguished)

[image]

am I doing something wrong?

I'm doing this in windows, in vim (not gvim)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both colorschemes only support terminal emulators capable of displaying 256 colors and GUI Vim. Since the Windows console only supports 16 colors they simply can't work.

You have two options:

1. use GVim or a better terminal emulator if you absolutely want to use any of those colorschemes,
2. find a colorscheme that works with the Windows console.

Comment: rats, I figured the windows terminal would have 256 :/